# Entity Framework produces a buggy query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, join

Here is the C# query we have:

```
return this.unitOfWork.Questions
    .WhereIdIsAnyOf(ids)
    .Select(q => q.ApplicationFormSection.ApplicationForm.EApplication.ECase.ID);
```

(`WhereIdIsAnyOf` is just an extension method that produces a fixed-length `IN` statement)

**NOTE** that `Question.ApplicationFormSection` is a nullable relation and hence could have a `NULL` foreign key.

The query that it produces is:

```
DISTINCT [Join3].[ECase_ID] AS [ECase_ID]
FROM    [dbo].[Questions] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ApplicationFormSections] AS [Extent2] 
    ON [Extent1].[ApplicationFormSection_ID] = [Extent2].[ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ApplicationForms] AS [Extent3] 
    ON [Extent2].[ApplicationForm_ID] = [Extent3].[ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
    (   SELECT [Extent4].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], [Extent4].    [ECase_ID] AS [ECase_ID], [Extent5].[ID] AS [ID1]
        FROM  [dbo].[EApplications] AS [Extent4]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ApplicationForms] AS [Extent5] 
            ON [Extent4].[ID] = [Extent5].[ID] 
    ) AS [Join3] 
    ON (([Extent3].[ID] = [Join3].[ID1]) OR (([Extent3].[ID] IS NULL) AND     ([Join3].[ID1] IS NULL)))
WHERE ([Extent1].[ID] IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

-- *I've dropped some unimportant parts for simplicity*

`([Extent3].[ID] = [Join3].[ID1]) OR (([Extent3].[ID] IS NULL) AND ([Join3].[ID1] IS NULL))` clause is what EF typically uses to testify the equality of two IDs but  **IT TURNS OUT BUGGY IN THIS CASE** because those IDs are not actually null but get null value in the query as a result of the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

### Workaround is this... but why?

Adding a `.Where(a => a.ApplicationFormSection != null)` will sort the problem out

but am I correct thinking this is a bug in EF? or at least some situation it can't cope with?

This is very catastrophic for us because a query that looks like it's job is to retrieve a single ID from a 1:1 relationship, suddenly returns 1000s of IDs.

Comment: It should be easy to come up with a self-contained test program (without need for a database) that prints the bad query. That would show clearly where the problem is. Without that, you have removed so much that you say is irrelevant that there is a fair chance one of the things actually is relevant after all.

Comment: Can you show the code for `WhereIdIsAnyOf`?

Comment: @Aducci here is the code for that, however it's totally irrelevant and only produces the final IN clause. https://gist.github.com/mvalipour/b9bbd716b3752871d5a2